# Change a grid website template from 3 column to 2 column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

**Edit: still in need of help with this question**

I need to completely delete the <nav> item from  the HTML and  CSS

The problem is that I don't understand grid layouts, I am learning, so I don't really know how to do it and the 1fr part and the minmax(75px, auto) /* Nav */ I cannot understand that part in this template.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "nav content side" "footer footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 200px;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: #baffc9;
  height: 100px;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  background: red;
}

main {
  grid-area: content;
}

aside {
  grid-area: side;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  background: #ffdfba;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: #bae1ff;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-areas: "header" "nav" "content" "side" "footer";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto/* Header */
    minmax(75px, auto)/* Nav */
    1fr/* Content */
    minmax(75px, auto)/* Sidebar */
    auto;
    /* Footer */
  }
  nav,
  aside {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    this is the header
  </header>
  <nav>
    this red one must die
  </nav>
  <main>
    this is the main
  </main>
  <aside>
    this is the aside
  </aside>
  <footer>
    this is the footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

I would like to understand and to completely delete this item from the CSS to learn how it is done

Comment: There are countless of ressources to learn more about `grid`, [CSS Grid Layout - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout) is one.

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I am learning so this answer is very pedagogic

Comment: After reading the docs, do you still have questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's decrypt step by step what's going on and what changes are needed.

### Desktop

1. **grid-template-areas**

```
grid-template-areas: 
  "header header header" 
  "nav content side" 
  "footer footer footer";
```

It represents the area of the grid.
Every line is one line of your grid, every item in each line is a column.
It means:

- the `header` area will occupy the first line and span across the 3 columns
- the second line will have 3 columns, first is occupied by the `nav`, second is for the `content`, third for the `side`
- the footer will occupy the third line and span across the 3 columns

If you want to remove the `nav`, you'll get a layout with only 2 columns:

```
grid-template-areas: 
  "header header" 
  "content side" 
  "footer footer";
```

2. **grid-template-columns**

```
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 200px;
```

It means that the first and the third columns will take `200px`, the second one will take the remaining space.
You need to remove the first column:

```
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 200px;
```

### Mobile

1. **grid-template-areas**
   You just need to remove the nav area:

```
  grid-template-areas: "header" "content" "side" "footer";
```

2. **grid-template-rows**:
   The nav area was the second row, you can simply delete it:

```
    grid-template-rows: auto/* Header */
    1fr/* Content */
    minmax(75px, auto)/* Sidebar */
    auto;
    /* Footer */
```

If you want to understand what `minmax(75px, auto)/* Nav */` means, it's quite straight forward:
The nav would have had a minimum height of `75px` and a maximum height `auto` so it would have taken the space needed by it's content.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "content side" "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 200px;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: #baffc9;
  height: 100px;
}

main {
  grid-area: content;
}

aside {
  grid-area: side;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  background: #ffdfba;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: #bae1ff;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-areas: "header" "content" "side" "footer";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto/* Header */
    1fr/* Content */
    minmax(75px, auto)/* Sidebar */
    auto;
    /* Footer */
  }
  aside {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    this is the header
  </header>
  <main>
    this is the main
  </main>
  <aside>
    this is the aside
  </aside>
  <footer>
    this is the footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer explained it all :) thanks a lot Amaury

Comment: Just to be sure: content side, is it not (main side) there? Because I see no item with the content name neither class nor ID

Comment: It will impact your element `main`and you element `side`, but as you can see on the definition of `main`, you have: `main { grid-area: content; }`. It means that it will be placed on the area of the grid named `content`: `grid-template-areas: "header header" "content side" "footer footer";`. This name is arbitrary, it could be Nicolas or superDuperDiv.